# custom radio buttons need to display value as the original input

Tags: jquery, html, css, addclass, removeclass

I am trying to make custom radio buttons, for that, I have to hide the original input and do it with icons instead.

Adding and removing the class "checked" works fine, but it has to change, at the same time the icon, displaying the cross if it is not checked, or the check if it is checked. And.... I just can't understand how it should work so obviously... trying to do the jquery as I am doing it doesn't have much sense....

Also, because they are radio buttons, when you click the checked radio button, it shouldn't change, so it needs to be checked, if the user clicks the unchecked radio button, the checked one will stop being checked, and the one the user clicked last will become checked (I think I haven't explained this very well, they just need to behave exactly as radio buttons).
Anyone can give me a hand with this?

html:

```
  <div class="price_type">
           <p>PRICE TYPE</p>
           <div class="radiobutton checked">
             <label>
               <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               <input name="price_type" value="retail" id="retail" type="radio" checked>
               <span class="text">RETAIL</span>
             </label>
           </div>
           <div class="radiobutton">
             <label>
               <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               <input name="price_type" value="inBond" id="inBond" type="radio">
               <span class="text">IN BOND</span>
             </label>
           </div>
         </div>
```

css:

```
.radiobutton {
          display: inline-block;
          padding-left: 10px;
      }

      .radiobutton label input[type="radio"],
       .radiobutton label span {
          vertical-align:middle;
          position:relative;
          font-weight: 100;
      }
      .radiobutton label i{
          color:#979797;
          z-index:1;
          cursor: pointer;
          font-size: 1.5em;
      }
      .radiobutton label input[type="radio"] {
          display:block;
      }
      .radiobutton.checked label i {
        color:blue;

      }
```

js:

```
var iconRadiobutton = $('.radiobutton label i');

    $(iconRadiobutton).on('click', function(){
        $(iconRadiobutton).parent().parent().removeClass("checked");
        if($(this).hasClass("fa-check")) {
           $(this).toggleClass("fa-check fa-cross ");
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass("fa-cross")) {
        $(this).toggleClass("fa-cross fa-check");
        }
        $(this).parent().parent(".radiobutton").addClass("checked");  
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tj7Lb1sv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm are to lazy make example from your code so I passing mu code what i used, i hope you can adapt this four your needs, for example for **X** or **V** you can use :before and :affer on *label*

```
<ul class="inputs-group">
    <li class="button-input-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" id="room-1" class="button-input run-search" name="rooms" value="1">
        <label class="button-label" for="room-1">1h</label>
    </li>
    <li class="button-input-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" id="room-2" class="button-input run-search" name="rooms" value="2">
        <label class="button-label" for="room-2">2h</label>
    </li>
    <li class="button-input-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" id="room-3" class="button-input run-search" name="rooms" value="3">
        <label class="button-label" for="room-3">3h</label>
    </li>
    <li class="button-input-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" id="room-4" class="button-input run-search" name="rooms" value="4+">
        <label class="button-label" for="room-4">4h+</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.inputs-group-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.inputs-group-wrap .inputs-group {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.button-input-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.button-input-wrap .button-input {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
}

.button-input-wrap .button-label {
    height: 43px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 21px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #b2d8e1;
    background-color: #c1e8ef;
    color: #3a8da9;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

.button-input-wrap .button-input:checked ~ .button-label {
    border: 1px solid #de6328;
    background-color: #de6328;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
.toggleClass("fa-check fa-times");
```

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.radiobutton :radio').on('change', function(e) {
    $('.radiobutton label i').toggleClass("fa-check fa-times");
  })
});
```

```css
.radiobutton {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.radiobutton label input[type="radio"],
.radiobutton label span {
  vertical-align:middle;
  position:relative;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.radiobutton label span.icon {
  color:#979797;
  z-index:1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.radiobutton label input[type="radio"] {
  display:block;
}
.radiobutton.checked label span.icon {
  color:brown;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="price_type">
    <p>PRICE TYPE</p>
    <div class="radiobutton checked">
        <label>
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input name="price_type" value="retail" id="retail" type="radio" checked>
            <span class="text">RETAIL</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radiobutton">
        <label>
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input name="price_type" value="inBond" id="inBond" type="radio">
            <span class="text">IN BOND</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is $(this).next('i').trigger('change'); does? I mean.... this .trigger('change') what is it triggering?

Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry gaetanoM, I just can't get it to work properly..... As now the class "checked" that does the color does not match and I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

So..... What I am supposed to do is: when the radio button (original input), changes, I toggle the class for the icon and the class for the radiobutton to be also with the class "checked". But then.... it gets crazy! so how the function knows if I am clicking one twice for example? I am sorry.... I know I am very short understanding stuff..... :(

Comment: @eve_mf A last question: does my snippet work? If my snippet works this means you are missing libraries or their version. Take a look to the libraries I used. Let me know.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Well, I have discovered, it wasn't working as it works in the jsfiddle with your snippet because I haven't put those inputs inside a form! O___O as soon as I wrapped them in a form it started behaving as yours. I thought it wasn't necessary to put radio buttons inside a form..... well.... I have learnt something new ^_^ thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: @eve_mf I'm happy for you. In any case, what is actually important you solved your problem. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score -1):

The custom radio button has to be a `label` w/ the `for` attribute identical to the `id` of the `input` its replacing. For example:

```
<input id="foobar" type="radio">
<label for="foobar">
```

[A working example](https://codepen.io/mitchmc/pen/pebIx).

Comment: that is not why it is not working, in fact.... I can't have an id for each radio button... I have hundreds of them....